# Convert a string value in a column of a data frame into timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with timestamp values that contain few string values as shown below.

[image]

I want to replace the 'N/A' with `00:00` timestamp.

Tried doing it with the below code but it did'nt work

```py
df['Execution_time_6'] = pivot_data['Execution_time_6'].replace('N/A','00:00')
```

Comment: Can you copy in some data rather than / as well as a picture, preferably with any code you have used so far. For example, what you have posted is confusing  - is pivot_data a different pandas dataframe? If so how does it relate to df?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the exact datatype of that column, and on whether the `N/A` is really a string itself or just how a missing value is displayed. If it is indeed a missing value, you may want to use `fillna()` instead of `replace()`. For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['15:16', '15:16', '15:16', np.nan]},
                  dtype='string')
df.fillna('00:00', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
   time
0  15:16
1  15:16
2  15:16
3  00:00
```